# Vuejs/Vuex How to remove(filter) an Object inside an Array of Objects in vuex state using mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm try to remove an Object inside my nested(Object->Array->Objcet) vuex state.

The scenario of my application is so:

**1.** I will send the request to the back-end to delete a record and then return a response with just a message. Then commit to vuex state`UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_TO_CLASSROOM`. Everything here works fine.

```
    async unassignCoursandTeacher({ commit }, classroom) {
      let response = await Axios.post(
         "/dashboard/school/unassignCoursandTeacher/" + classroom.id, classroom
      );
      let cls = response.data;
      if (
         response.status == 200 ||
         response.status == 201 ||
         response.status == 204
      ) {
         commit("UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_TO_CLASSROOM", cls);
         return cls;
      }
    }
```

1. Now I want to updated `singleClassroom` State with the help of mutations. But it doesn't remove the delete item in State. Only if I refresh the page. below is how the mutation is setup.

   ```
   `UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_TO_CLASSROOM(state, cls) {
       let cours = state.singleClassroom.courses.filter(c => c.id != cls);
       state.singleClassroom.courses = cours;
    }`
   ```

Here is the stricture of my data in vuex state:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is perfectly fine. But in one of your sentence you mentioned that "***I will send the request to the back-end to delete a record and then return a response with just a message.***" Which means that you are not returning any data except a json message( I assume). Which means `cls` is empty and you are trying to filter `singleClassroom` State with an empty value. That will definitely will not work.

So I will suggest to set the ID of the course your trying to filter inside your `ACTION`. Please see the code below:

**CHANGE THIS**

```
async unassignCoursandTeacher({ commit }, classroom) {
  let response = await Axios.post(
    "/dashboard/school/unassignCoursandTeacher/" + classroom.id,classroom
  );
  let cls = response.data; // You are assigning cls to an empty attribute - this where the issue is.
  if (
     response.status == 200 ||
     response.status == 201 ||
     response.status == 204
   ) {
     commit("UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_FROM_CLASSROOM", cls);
     return cls;
  }
}
```

**TO THIS**

```
async unassignCoursandTeacher({ commit }, classroom) {
  let response = await Axios.post(
    "/dashboard/school/unassignCoursandTeacher/" + classroom.id,classroom
  );
  
  if (
     response.status == 200 ||
     response.status == 201 ||
     response.status == 204
   ) {
     let cls = classroom.yourCoursID; // Here we are assigning cls value to the cours ID.
     commit("UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_FROM_CLASSROOM", cls);
     return cls;
  }
}
```

Comment: @livresonLtc, Thanks a lot. I worked. That was my mistake.

Comment: May I suggest you use Typescript in the future, @MaddoxLMS. It will help you with such mistakes. It really is a gem.

Comment: @Tony, I never play with TypeScript. I heard good stuff about it. I don't know how hard is to use.

Comment: @livresonltc, there’s a learning curve, surely, but it’s worth it. It’s actually not that difficult to use. I learnt the basic stuff within a week. It’s pretty great and it also helps with refactoring. I would never again write JavaScript without typescript unless it’s a tiny project - that’s how good it is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I agree with @Rodrigo. The Vuex state is reactive as `data` property in your components and I imagine you defined the singleClassroom data (including the courses property) in your vuex state, making it reactive. I don't believe this situation applies to the [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) listed here.

I don't know what `cls` is, but I doubt it stands for an id. This is because you get cls from `response.data`. I strongly suspect `cls` is the course you are trying to remove and you are filtering course Id against it and they aren't of the same type. May I also suggest you use strict equality (===) as it reduces the chances of bugs.

I think the problem may be here

```js
UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_TO_CLASSROOM(state, cls) {
    let cours = state.singleClassroom.courses.filter(c => c.id != cls); // if cls is the course, I think you are filtering the wrong thing
    state.singleClassroom.courses = cours;
}
```

Try changing to

```js
UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_TO_CLASSROOM(state, cls) {
    let cours = state.singleClassroom.courses.filter(c => c.id !== cls.id);
    state.singleClassroom.courses = cours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Vue.set( target, propertyName/index, value )` to update your object.

*Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property additions (e.g. this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi').*

```
UNASSIGN_COURS_AND_TEACHER_TO_CLASSROOM(state, cls) {
    let cours = state.singleClassroom.courses.filter(c => c.id != cls);
    Vue.set(state.singleClassroom, 'courses', cours);
 }
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set